# Spring MVC: Forward instead of redirect

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Is it possible to invoke an spring controller/action without redirecting?

I do not want the browser to refresh to the new url.

Comment: Using a view name of `forward:/other/url` ? Is it all you need ?

Comment: No, that won't do since it will only work from an action. But I figured it out, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("").forward(request, response); // For "/" 

request.getRequestDispatcher("home/register").forward(request, response);
```